# Рост ошибки при обучении

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Нейронная сеть имеет архитектуру [323667, 500, 1] и sigmoid в качестве функции активации. Вот код ее обучения:

```py
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
    alpha = 0.001

    weights_0_1 = 0.2*np.random.random((len(dictionary), 500)) - 0.1
    weights_1_2 = 0.2*np.random.random((500, 1)) - 0.1

    for i in range(1, 13998):
        data = one_hot_code(get_train_data(i)[2])
        right = float(get_train_data(i)[1])
        hidden_layer = sigmoid(np.sum(weights_0_1[data], axis=0))
        output_layer = sigmoid(np.dot(hidden_layer, weights_1_2))

        output_delta = output_layer - right
        hidden_delta = output_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)

        weights_1_2 = weights_1_2 - alpha * hidden_layer * output_delta
        weights_0_1 -= alpha * np.array(data).reshape([323667,1]).dot(hidden_delta.reshape([1, 500]))

        error = np.mean((output_delta - right) ** 2)
        print(i, "Error:", error)
```

Сеть должна прогнозировать результат от 1 до 0, но при обучении на тех точках данных, где нейросеть должна прогнозировать 1, ошибка падает, а на тех точках, где сеть должна прогнозировать 0, она растет. Менял альфа-коэффициент от 0.1 до 0.000000001 - безуспешно. В чём моя ошибка?